# Permissions changed after vhosts setup

Tags: permissions, apache2, virtualhost

I have running php project on Ubuntu 20 , After having configured for it apacher vhosts , the permisssions of the folder and its content has changed and become not writable ,
How can I prevent this from happening another time ;
example of method I am using

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/webserver1.com.conf
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/webserver1.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@webserver1.com
   ServerName webserver1.com
   ServerAlias www.webserver1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/webserver1.com/public_html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So you're using Ubuntu Core 20 and not Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: To clarify, *which user* cannot write data? The account used to upload the files or `www-data`?

Comment: www-data cannot write data locally